# Transcode video with php ffmpeg library

Tags: php, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I need to upload video in 3 formate/resolution as 360p, 480p, 720p.

After some research i got to know that some paid service are there like **Amazone Elastic Transcoder** . But i want to do with open source so i found **FFMPEG**.

Also i want to upload video on **Amazon s3** after transcode and video are in big size like video may contain **1GB** size.

I got php library for **FFMPEG** [Library Link](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)

I have installed ffmpeg and it successfully generate new video. But i cannot figure out that how can i generate different **formate/resolution as 360p, 480p, 720p**.

My sample Code is

```
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        require 'vendor/autoload.php';

        //$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
        $video = $ffmpeg->open('assets/small.mp4');
        $video
            ->filters()
            ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
            ->synchronize();
        $video
            ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(2))
            ->save('assets/frame.jpg');

        $format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
        $format->setAudioCodec("libmp3lame");

        $video->save($format, 'assets/new.mp4');
```

Can anyone suggest me any way that how can i achieve this ??

Answer (score 4):

Am pretty sure you figured this out already but am putting this here for future reference.

```
// Create the formats in Kilo Bitrates
$_360p = (new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame'))->setKiloBitrate(500);
$_480p = (new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame'))->setKiloBitrate(750);
$_720p = (new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame'))->setKiloBitrate(1500);
// Open the video file
$video = $ffmpeg->open('assets/small.mp4')
                // Add all formats
                ->addFormat($_360p)
                ->addFormat($_480p)
                ->addFormat($_720p)
                // call the 'save' method with a filename...
                ->save('assets/new.mp4');
```